# DEBIAN repository signing: a step-by-step guide

Tags: linux, debian, synaptic

I've got many DEBIAN repository for my projects (e.g. [EPAPI](http://code.google.com/p/epapi/), [erlang-dbus](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-dbus/) etc.).
It seems that now Synaptic wants those to be signed for the packages to appear by default.

For the DEBIAN kung-fu masters out there, please provide me with a step-by-step guide to achieving this, please.  I've googled a lot but I am still a bit confused on the subject.

**update:** I use a Launchpad PPA now... saves me from all this trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I use the [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/) tool - it does it automatically for me.  Yes, this is a tool to manage a whole repository, but it also automatically signs them and asks for my passphrase every time I add a new package.

Comment: I do not want to mirror repos, I want to **sign** my repos: how does reprepro help on this?

Comment: @jldupont: I use reprepro as a tool to manage my own repository, not to mirror one.  It works perfectly for it, and my repository gets signed.

Answer (score 3):

The Debian wiki has some automated options:
http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository

But for the simple case the "howto" appears to be:
http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#Settingupasecureaptrepository

This bit from the install instructions might help:
http://people.debian.org/~osamu/pub/getwiki/html/ch02.en.html#_top_level_release_file_and_authenticity

If you're creating by hand it looks like none of the basic tools have an option to create release files so you might have to deal with apt-ftparchive or similar anyway.